# display enum values inside winforms combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Let's say that I have following enum

```
public enum MyMode { A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4 };
```

and I want to use this enum as list of values inside combobox, I tried with

```
cmbMyMode.Items.Add(Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyMode )));
```

but I'm getting following

```
MyMode[] Array
```

I need to display A, B, C, D, and is it possible to use custom string instead of A,B,C,D

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
List<MyMode> modes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyMode)).Cast<MyMode>().ToList();
cmbMyMode.DataSource = modes;
```

And to customize the labels:

```
var modes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyMode)).Cast<MyMode>().Select(mode => 
                   new { Value = mode, Title = string.Format("-->{0}<--", mode) }).
                 ToList();
cmbMyMode.ValueMember = "Value";
cmbMyMode.DisplayMember = "Title";
cmbMyMode.DataSource = modes;
```

and then

```
cmbMyMode.SelectedValue
```

Comment: @CarlosLanderas why do you think so? It's tagged as `c#`

Comment: My comment was addressed to Carlos Landeras.

Comment: @vc74 great, is it possible to use this (A,B,C,D) with concatenated string on the same line?

Comment: @user1765862 Do you mean a custom display while keeping the value?

Comment: string.Format("-->{0}<--", mode) lol on the goatse, cant ever unsee it.

Answer (score 3):

```
  cmbMyMode.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyMode)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyMode)))
{
    cmbMyMode.Items.Add(name);
}
```